# single post api data not rendering in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to react-hooks. I have successfully been able to load all objects coming from the api. But when I try to load a single post, it renders the object with id=1 only. I have 3 data in the backend database.

**I am using Axios inside useEffect function.**

My foodpage:

```
function Food() {

  const [food, setFood] = useState([])
  const [id,setId] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://texas-crm1.herokuapp.com/api/menus/${id}`)
    .then(abc=>{
      console.log(abc.data)
      // console.log(abc.data.id);
      setFood(abc.data)
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err) 
    })
  }, [])


 return (
  <div>
    <div className="food-page">   
      
       <PageHeader  {...food} key={food.id} />;       
       <Customize />
       <FoodDescription  {...food} key={food.id} />;
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default Food;
```

Here, initially, i have put the state as id =1. And I am stuck how to change the state. Thats why on every food description only id=1 is rendered.

My food description:

```
function FoodDescription(props) {

  const [quantity,setQuantity] = useState(0)
  // let quantity = 0;

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    if (quantity > 0){
      setQuantity((prev) => prev - 1);
    }
    else {
            setQuantity(0);
          }   
      
  };

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setQuantity((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  console.log(props);
  const {food_name,long_title,subtitle,description,price,id} = props;

  return (
    <div className="food-description">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="title">
            <div className="main-title">{food_name}</div>
          </div>
          <div className="description">
            {/* {description.map((des: string, index: number) => { */}
            {/* {description.map((des, index) => {  
              return <p key={index}>{des}</p>;
            })} */}
            {description}
            {/* <div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML="description">{description}</div> */}
          </div>
          <div className="order">
            <div className="quantity">
              {/* <div className="negative" onClick={() => this.handleDecrement()}>
                -
              </div>
              {this.state.quantity}
              <div className="positive" onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}>
                +
              </div> */}
              <div className="negative" onClick={handleDecrement}>-</div>
                {quantity}
              <div className="negative" onClick={handleIncrement}>
                +
              </div>
            </div>
            <ExploreButton active="link-active">
              Add to Order - ${price}
            </ExploreButton>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}


export default FoodDescription;
```

[image]

Here are three different foods. But when I click on anyone of them, only id=1 is rendered in Fooddescription page.

**Update:**

Components that contains the click button on **Buy Now.**

My MenuComponent.txs

```
const MenuComponent = (props: any) => {
   console.log(props);
   
  const {id,category, image,price,rating,food_name,description} = props;
  // const starterMenu = starter.map
  const starterMenu = [
    {
      id :id,
      thumbnail: image,
      title: category,
      rating: rating,
      description:description,       
      price: price,
    },
    {
      id :id,
      thumbnail: image,
      title: category,
      rating: rating,
      description:description,
      price: price,
    },
    {
      id :id,
      thumbnail: image,
      title: category,
      rating: rating,
      description:description,        
      price: price,
    },
    {
      id :id,
      thumbnail: image,
      title: category,
      rating: rating,
      description:description,
      price: price,
    },
  ];

  const renderMenuList = () => {
    switch (props.category) {
      case "starters":
        return <Starters />;

      case "main courses":
        return <MainCourses />;

      case "soups & salads":
        return <SoupsSalads />;

      case "sliders":
        return <Sliders />;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="menu-component">
      <div className="title">
        <div className="main-title">{props.category}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="menu-cards">
        {starterMenu.map((starterItem, index) => {
          return <MenuCard {...starterItem} key={index} />;
        })}
      </div>
      {renderMenuList()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuComponent;
```

**The props are passed to MenuCard. My MenuCard is as follows**:

```
const MenuCard = (props: any) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    // Menu card
    <div className="menu-card">
      <div className="container">
        {/* Thumbnail */}
        <div className="thumbnail">
          <img src={props.thumbnail} alt={props.title} />
        </div>

        {/* Title */}
        <div className="title">{props.title}</div>

        {/* Star rating */}
        <div className="rating">
          <StarRating rating={props.rating} />
        </div>

        {/* description */}
        <div className="description">{props.description}</div>

        <div className="bottom">
          {/* price */}
          <div className="price">{props.price}</div>
          <Link to={`/menu/${props.id}`}>
            <MenuButton highlighted="highlighted">Buy Now</MenuButton>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuCard;
```

**Update:2**

[image]

[image]

When i go to menu it shows all the food items, And when I click on one of the Buy, now it shows correct id in the url. But still id=1 food details are shown.

Comment: "But when I click on anyone of them" -> can you add the code for this part as well ? . The code containing your list of cards .

Comment: Hello @Shyam I have updated the code. Can you please check?

Comment: which component is getting rendered when you hit the route `/menu/{props.id}` ?

Comment: I see that all cards defined in `starterMenu` has the same id, so how do you expect it to render another id on every card click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you click `Buy Now` you hit the route /menu/:someId which renders the `<Food />`.

Since the selected menu's id is in the URL we can make use of the `useParams` hook to get the id and fire the API call. Your current code doesn't work because irrespective of the Menu Card you clicked you will always fire the API call for the `id` 1 . As you have hardcoded it . So to make it dynamic you can do this

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Food() {
  const [food, setFood] = useState([]);

  // if your route is /menu/:menuId 
  const { menuId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://texas-crm1.herokuapp.com/api/menus/${menuId}`)
      .then((abc) => {
        console.log(abc.data);
        // console.log(abc.data.id);
        setFood(abc.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="food-page">
        <PageHeader {...food} key={food.id} />;
        <Customize />
        <FoodDescription {...food} key={food.id} />;
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Reference

[useParams Hook](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

Comment: I did as you said, putting id as useparams,now nothing is being rendered, previously only id 1 was shown.

Comment: Still some information is missing in your question . when your <Food /> component is rendered what is the url you see in browser ? . Show the code for your route's as well .

Comment: hello shyam, i have added 2 pics, one showing for all foods in menu and one is fooddetails page which is like menu/2

Comment: Did you remove this `const [id,setId] = useState(1)` from your component ?

Comment: Nono I have used it in place of useparams.

Comment: I am confused now . You have to remove the `const [id,setId] = useState(1)` and replace it with the useParams as i have mentioned in the answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236021/discussion-between-shyam-and-django-rocks).